# Run query within foreach loop in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Basically i'm trying to build a comment system. The user looks at a photo on the site, and then can view all the comments made by other members.

Each comment will be looped out using a foreach (currently working fine), but what I need to do is then run a seperate query for each comment to get the user details of the user who posted it. These details are stored on a seperate database (otherwise i'd just do a join).

My model has this in it so far:

```
public function get_comment($id)
{
    $db_photos = $this->load->database('photos', TRUE);
    $db_photos->select('id, comment, userid, photoid');
    $db_photos->from('comments');
    $db_photos->where('photoid', $id);

    return $db_photos->get()->result();
}
```

And here's the controller:

```
public function view($id)
    {   

        $data['comment'] = $this->viewphoto_model->get_comment($id);
        if (empty($data['comment'])) { show_404(); }

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('viewphoto/viewphoto', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
```

And then the view:

```
<?php foreach ($comment as $comments): ?>
        <div class="ViewPhoto-CommentsBox">
        <? echo $comments->comment; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

So basically I need to grab the 'userid' value from each comment and then run a query on the 'users' database to get the user details for each comment posted.

Any help is most appreciated :)

EDIT:

Still not working, here's latest version.

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Viewphoto extends CI_Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('viewphoto_model');
    }


    public function view($id)
    {
        $data['photo'] = $this->viewphoto_model->get_photo($id);
        if (empty($data['photo'])) { show_404(); }

        $data['user'] = $this->viewphoto_model->get_user($data['photo']->userid);
        if (empty($data['user'])) { show_404(); }


        $comment = $this->viewphoto_model->get_comment($id);
        if($comment->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach ($comment->result() as $r)
                {
                    $data['reg'][$i]['comment']=$r->comment;
                    $data['reg'][$i]['id']=$r->id;           

                   // Get user details from user table
                    $user_profile = $this->viewphoto_model->get_comment_user($r->userid);
                    if($user_profile->num_rows() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach ($user_profile->result() as $row)
                        {
                            // user details whatever you have in your db.
                            $data['reg'][$i]['id']=$row->id;
                            $data['reg'][$i]['firstname']=$row->firstname;
                            $data['reg'][$i]['lastname']=$row->lastname;
                        }
                    }

                    $i++;
                }
            }

        $data['title'] = $data['photo']->title.' by '.$data['user']->firstname.' '.$data['user']->lastname;
        $data['meta_description'] = $data['photo']->description;
        $data['directory'] = 'sub';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('viewphoto/viewphoto', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Viewphoto_model extends CI_Model {


    public function get_photo($id)
    {
        $db_photos = $this->load->database('photos', TRUE);
        $db_photos->select('*');
        $db_photos->select("DATE_FORMAT(uploaddate, '%d/%m/%y') as uploaddate_formatted", FALSE);
        $db_photos->from('photos');
        $db_photos->where('approved', '1');
        $db_photos->where('id', $id);

        return $db_photos->get()->row();
    }

    public function get_user($userid)
    {
        $db_users = $this->load->database('users', TRUE);
        $db_users->select('id, firstname, lastname, email, type, type_staff, count_approved, count_sales, count_comments, count_editorial, featured, subscriber');
        $db_users->from('useraccounts');
        $db_users->where('id', $userid);

        return $db_users->get()->row();
    }


    public function get_comment($id)
    {
        $db_photos = $this->load->database('photos', TRUE);
        $db_photos->select('id, comment, userid, photoid');
        $db_photos->from('comments');
        $db_photos->where('photoid', $id);

        return $db_photos->get()->result();
    }


    public function get_comment_user($userid)
    {
        $db_users = $this->load->database('users', TRUE);
        $db_users->select('id, firstname, lastname');
        $db_users->from('useraccounts');
        $db_users->where('id', $userid);

        return $db_users->get();
    }

}
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($reg as $comments): ?>
        <div class="ViewPhoto-CommentsBox">
        <? echo $comments['comment']; ?> by <? echo $comments['firstname'];?>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: I have no experience with codeigniter but querying within a loop is I believe generally a bad idea, Personally I'd do something like get the user details as you have with comments then use some nested loop to 'join' the two.

Comment: The reason for the query of the loop is so that if a user changes their user details it changes for all comments they have made throughout the site. I can't put their user details into each row of the comment database becuase it means it won't change dynamically. Unless when they change thheir details I write something to change all comments in the entire database, but that sounds a bit crazy.

Comment: Hi, I think you have misinterpreted what I have said, I am not suggesting you change the data/database in anyway, rather obtain two models in say your controller, parse them to the view where you could loop through them appropriately. Alternatively play with your comment model to obtain/map the information from the other db.

Comment: Hi so at the bottom of http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html it shows an example of multiple database connections. As I have said I have no experience of codigniter but it looks like a resolution could be handled in your `get_comment` method quite easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your controller like this.

```
 public function view($id)
        {       
              $comment= $this->viewphoto_model->get_comment($id);

              if($comment->num_rows() > 0)
                {
                    foreach ($comment->result() as $r)
                    {
                        $data['reg'][$i]['comment']=$r->comment;
                        $data['reg'][$i]['id']=$r->id;           

                       // Get user details from user table
                        $user_profile=$this->viewphoto_model->get_user_profile_details($r->userid);
                        if($user_profile->num_rows() > 0)
                        {
                            foreach ($user_profile->result() as $row)
                            {
                                // user details whatever you have in your db.
                                $data['reg'][$i]['name']=$row->name;
                                $data['reg'][$i]['gender']=$row->gender;
                                $data['reg'][$i]['phone_no']=$row->phone_no;
                            }
                        }

                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('viewphoto/viewphoto', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
        }
```

View file: you can use details like below.

```
<?php if(isset($reg)) { foreach ($reg as $comments): ?>
        <div class="ViewPhoto-CommentsBox">
        <? echo $comments['comment']; ?>
         <? echo $comments['name']; // user detail ?>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <? } ?>
```

Comment: Hmmm...looks good but doesn't seem to work. I just get a blank white screen. I have updated my original question with the full controller and model.

Comment: change in your model function get_comment().  return $db_photos->get(); instead of return $db_photos->get()->result();

Comment: Now I get the following error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: i

Filename: controllers/viewphoto.php

Line Number: 27. Also one for line 28 as well, same error.

Comment: Actually ignore my previous comment. It now gives this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: reg

Filename: viewphoto/viewphoto.php

Line Number: 110

Comment: And this one too: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: viewphoto/viewphoto.php

Line Number: 110

Comment: I shocked why your code not getting error right now i feel good. just declare $i=0; at start of controller function.

Comment: It's almost working now. Only issue is that if there are 0 comments, I get an error since the $reg variable doesn't exist. I can't figure out how to just echo a bit of text, since you can't put a foreach loop inside an if statement...

Comment: Yeah that's what I was trying to do but you can't put a foreach inside an if statement. Yep I was going to accept your answer as soon as I got it all working :)

Comment: Yah I already tried that, it doesn't work. I don't think you can put a foreach loop inside an if statement.

Comment: we can use foreach inside if. see controller function. Can you tell me the error you got?

Comment: try to print something in else part of if(isset($reg)).

Comment: Actually no it's not. This is wierd, now I get a blank white page.

Comment: lol, actually it is. All working great, I echoed out a message in the else part too. Thanks for your help srbhbarot! :)

Answer (score 0):

that's working ! :

```
$searchquery = "SELECT * FROM your_table";
        $resultquery = $this->db->query($searchquery);
        $i = 0;
        if($resultquery->num_rows() > 0)
                {
                    foreach ($resultquery->result() as $query)
                    {
                        $data['reg'][$i]['id']=$query->id;
                        $data['reg'][$i]['name']=$query->name;
                        $data['reg'][$i]['pers']=$query->pers;
                        $data['reg'][$i]['sex']=$query->sex;
                        $i++;
                    }
            }
```

And for the view :

```
<?php if(isset($reg)) { foreach ($reg as $chambres): ?>
                    <li>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $query['id']; ?>" />
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $query['name']; ?>" placeholder="numero de la chambre" />
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $query['pers']; ?>" placeholder="Nombre de personne" />
                        <textarea><?php echo $query['sex']; ?></textarea>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                <?php } ?>
```

Thanks srbhbarot.